# MINITAB macro does not run

Tags: macros, minitab

I am learning MINITAB macros. Here is my attempt:
macro
Normal.
Random 25 'Normal';
Normal 0.0 1.0.
endmacro.

The file is saved as Normal.mac, Type of file MAC file(.mac)
The error I get is

- ERROR * Macro syntax error on line 5.
  Expecting a macro header. Found instead:  ..

Thanks for any help.

Pretty much tried everything I could think of (like macre replaced with gmacro). Funny, how can MINITAB make such a simple thing so complicated? Again, thanks for any help.